# Jquery slider left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this jQuery slider when it's on the last slide it comes back to the first one, but I can't manage to do the same on the other side.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/uctr94ve/1/

```
'use strict';

$(function() {

//settings for slider
var width = 720;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 2000;
var currentSlide = 1;

//cache DOM elements
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
var $container = $('.container');
var $sliderprevious = $('.sliderprevious', $container);
var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    (slide1, pause);
}

function slide1() {
    $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '+=' + width
    }, animationSpeed, function() {
        if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 0;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 3600);
        }
    });
}

function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$sliderprevious
    .on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
    .on('mouseleave', startSlider)
    .on('click', slide1);

startSlider();

});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want it so that when you go back on the first slide, it goes to the last slide?

Comment: Yes this is what I want.